# Google App Engine gcloud crashed (unicodedecodeerror)

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Im follow step by step using this tutorial
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/quickstart

Im stoped on step deploy app

im run in terminal `gcloud app deploy`
and im have error

> gcloud crashed (unicodedecodeerror) 'ascii' codec can't encode
>   character in position 9-15 ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/51711926/5320906